# Iterate over numpy.ma array, ignoring masked values

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I would like to iterate over only unmasked values in a `np.ma.ndarray`.

With the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3], mask = [0, 1, 0])
for i in a:
    print i
```

I get:

```
1
--
3
```

I would like to get the following:

```
1
3
```

It seems like `np.nditer()` may be the way to go, but I don't find any [flags](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) that might specify this. How might I do this? Thanks!

Comment: A masked array is really 2 arrays, the base one, and the mask.  General purpose `numpy` code will just work with the base; that would include `nditer`.  It's only the `ma` methods/fuctions that can make use of the mask.

Comment: That clarifies the intention of the `nditer` `arraymask` flag for me. Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to pass the `ma` `data` and `mask` separately to the `nditer`, using this flag to identify the later.  But I haven't explored that feature.

Answer (score 9):

you want to use `a.compressed()`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3], mask = [0, 1, 0])
for i in a.compressed():
    print i
```

which gives:

```
1
3
```

Comment: Interesting.  Stripped of some details,  `a.compressed()` ends up doing `a._data.compress(~a._mask)`